# NoClassDefFound error after adding JARs to Android project

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror, dalvik, dex

I've been looking around the internet for hours now on how to solve this issue. There are many people who posted this on StackOverflow and many other websites but none of the solutions worked for me. I think that many of them are outdated.

**Here is what I've tried:**

- Putting the libraries in `libs/` and letting the project automatically handle them (Add them as a reference, convert with Dalvik, etc)
- Adding them like I would for a normal Java project using Build Path settings (Add external jars-->Go to order and export-->Check the checkbox for all jars)
- I tried the last step but without checking their checkboxes
- I even tried someone's suggestion to put them in the `assets/` folder
- I tried putting them in the `libs/` folder and adding them as internal jars in Build Path settings
- Deleting `bin/`-->Cleaning-->Rebuilding
  ...And much more

I'm guessing my issue is when I am deploying my app, the jars aren't being packaged in the apk like they are supposed to. I am using many different jars. I'm trying to use [jReddit](https://github.com/jReddit/jReddit) and it has A LOT of dependencies.

P.S. Also, there are several solutions that I tried but I didn't mention because when I went to run the program, they caused a `Dex Loader` error. I also tried many things to remove this problem as well but then it caused the NoClassDefFound error all over again.

**Edit:** Just wanted to mention that I am using Eclipse.

Comment: Do you have inside your dependencies, inside of your build.gradle file, some lines like this: `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` and `compile files('libs/yourJAR.jar')` ?

Comment: Sry, I just added an edit. I am using eclipse without Gradle. I was having a lot of issues using some dependencies in Gradle, they weren't properly up to date.

Comment: **Oh, Eclipse? Really?** Is a deprecated IDE, did you know? Consider migration to Android Studio ASAP!

Comment: I was using Android Studio but I can't stand it. I ran into many more issues than I am now. Also, I hate that there is no shortcut for auto-import. It would be too big of a hassle to switch.

Comment: Give it a second chance. Everything is easier and the migration is worth the hassle. You'll have some problems just the first hours. I insist, Eclipse is deprecated.

Comment: Ok, I will give it another chance. I am still up for solutions on Eclipse though.

Comment: I also recommend switching to Android Studio and Gradle; totally worth though might be painful at first

Comment: You can put it as an answer and I'll accept it. I guess people need to start converting.

Comment: @joaquin - Eclipse itself is not a deprecated IDE. The Android Development Tools plugin for it is.

Comment: @cricket_007 You're right, I misspoke.

Comment: Either way I understood what he meant. Eclipse isn't being deprecated anytime soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was switching to another IDE. Eclipse is no longer supported by Google for android development and this is probably why I was having this issue. **I switched to Android Studio** and it worked. Thanks [joaquin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2823516/joaquin)!